# Why pandas complain out of memory when I still have a lot of available memory?

Tags: python, pandas

My computer has 64gb RAM. I try using pandas to extract data from a TSV file of size 200gb. I tried to use pandas.read_csv to extract data chunk by chunk with each chunk being 50,000 data points but pandas complain out of memory. The largest I can get is 44,000 per chunk. However, when I do this and observe the memory usage, it is only 10% of my memory. Can I know why pandas complain out of memory when it is only using 10% of my memory.

Error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_msceleb2.py", line 71, in <module>
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_name, sep = '\t', chunksize = num_imgs_per_thread, header=None):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 113, in <lambda>
    BaseIterator.next = lambda self: self.__next__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 916, in __next__
    return self.get_chunk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 972, in get_chunk
    return self.read(nrows=size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1508, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:10415)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 882, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:10896)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 924, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:11437)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 911, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:11308)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 2024, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:27037)
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

top:[image]

Does pandas limit the size of each chunk?

Comment: 1 - Is each point a single float/double/etc. or are they rows, 2 - how are you checking the memory usage?

Comment: Are you sure this an memory issue ? Check CPU usage for additional pointers and indexes !

Comment: Are you using 64 bit version of Python installation and can you also check the memory usage of the dataframe using this df.memory_usage() from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html ?

Comment: @Ajean Each point is a row in the TSV file. I used "top" command in linux to check.

Comment: @dsgdfg CPU usage is also not full. I have 6 core, 12 threads. I am not sure if it is memory, but the error says out of memory.

Comment: @Sandeep memory usage for each chunk is 2mb, which is a far cry from 64gb.

Comment: You didn't say whether you are using 32 bit or 64 bit Python.  32 bits will limit you to 2GB per process on Windows.

Comment: @CS 64bit python using Ubuntu. Is there a way to increase the limit?

Comment: So, what *else* is using memory? You must have other processes running, how much are they using?

Comment: @Ajean top shows 10% memory usage and 40gb+ available.

Comment: I dunno then, it might be hard to diagnose here. You could try profiling your code - sometimes memory gets used for temporary operations and shoots up super high and back down so fast that you can't see it with something like top.

Comment: @Ajean the thing i find weird is that my data is 200gb and my memory is 64gb which means i should be able to hold one quarter of the data without problem. Now it is not even one tenth.

Comment: What I'm saying is there might an internal operation that uses several times more memory for a split second because of copy operations. A profiler would maybe help you identify if that's it or not

Comment: @Ajean how can i use a profiler? can you teach me how? thx

Comment: No, because if you Google "python memory profiler" the first hit that isn't an ad is [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) and it tells you everything *right there*. A little effort on your part, please.